# Need exact output

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL. I need to know SQL query to get the output of the following scenario.

I have a table `Campaign` with columns

```
Customer ID, Campaign Name, Campaign ID, Channel
```

The `Channel` can have one of these values:

```
Direct Email, Email, Both
```

How do I evaluate the channel through which the customer have been contacted for the campaign? For example, there are a few customers who have been contacted through both channels.

How do I get a count of customers who have been contacted through both channels? Kindly help me with the query.

Comment: For a really basic example, see [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp).

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Are you looking for customers that have been contacted in a campaign with `'Both'` channels or are you looking for customers that have been contacted across multiple campaigns via both channels (i.e. either at least once with `'Both'` or at least once with one channel and once with another?

Comment: Anyway: Have you even thought about how to write the query yourself? You are supposed to come here with a concrete problem. That's usually a query you tried but that fails or is incomplete. Example: "My query `select customer_id from campaign where channel = 'Both';` gets me all customers with campaings that used both channels, but I get duplicate results and I don't know how to avoid that."

Answer (score 1):

Its simple, I've given an example. You can check it manually.

```
select count(*) from (select count(*) as b from Campaign group by customer_id) as a where a.b=2;
```

Here, first we grouped them on the basis of customer_id which I've assumed to be distinct. Then counted those id's for which both channels have been used.

This is dummy case:

```
+------+------+
| id   | ch   |
+------+------+
|    1 | d    |
|    2 | d    |
|    2 | e    |
|    3 | d    |
|    4 | d    |
|    4 | e    |
|    5 | d    |
|    6 | e    |
+------+------+

inner query: (select count(*) from q group by id);
output: 

       +----------+
        | count(*) |
        +---------+
        |        1 |
        |        2 |
        |        1 |
        |        2 |
        |        1 |
        |        1 |
        +----------+
whole query: mysql> select count(*) 
from (select count(*) as b from q group by id) as a where a.b=2;
        +----------+
        | count(*) |
        +----------+
        |        2 |
        +----------+
```

1 row in set (0.00 sec)